When working on hot water line, is it sufficient to turn off main valve?
I want to reconfigure hot water lines above my water heater (setup described here: Reconfiguring this hot water line DIY-able? Best approach and any caveats?)
When I turn off the cold water supply to the water heater (or the main shutoff valve), no hot water comes from faucets after a short time. It seems hot water line is empty despite the tank still being full.
Is it ok to work on the hot water lines right above the tank?
A similar question was asked here: if i turn off cold water valve at hot water heater will the pressure in hot water line be empty? but it doesn’t give a conclusive answer.
Also, I have a mixing valve. Can a mixing valve, turned all the way to cold water (and cold water being turned off) be used as a shutoff valve?

What floor is the heater on and how many are there?

Heater is in basement and there are 2 floors above. Having said that, the pipes I am working at are directly above/next to the heater (see my link).

Ok, see my answer.  If you cut the hot water pipe without emptying the system you'll get water all over the heater, and if you do it with the main supply on there's a risk it'll be even worse.

I would also turn off the power to the tank.
The pressure to push the water up will be 0, but water will still be in the pipes, unless you open a hot water faucet above and drain some water from the tank.
After the work is done, turn on the tank valve to fill the tank with the faucet still open to bleed any air.
Once the tank is full and no air comes out of the faucet, turn off the faucet and turn the power to the tank back on.

if you don't turn off power and the water drains from the tank you instantly blow the resistive elements if they are active.  I typically use the relief valve to ensure the tank is full before energizing.

The pipes are not empty when you shut off the water, there just isn't pressure to push the water out the faucets. Per your comment above, there are two floors of pipes and fixtures above the heater. They remain full of water when you turn the supply off.
If you are cutting pipes to work on the tank or replace it, and it has shut offs of its own on both sides, you can turn them both off and all the water remaining in the pipes above will be held back.  If the heater only has one shut off even if it's the cold one, you should turn off the main supply to the house.  You are going to have to drain the lines above the tank in order to work on them.  To drain them you have to open faucets and if the main supply is still on, the faucets will feed water back into the tank through the hot pipes.
Turn off the main cold supply to the house, and turn off the tank heater at its switch or knob.  Then, empty all the pipes above the tank before you cut them so water doesn't pour on the tank, possibly wetting the electronics or insulation.  To do that open hot and cold faucets on each floor and use the tank drain with a garden hose.
There's no way to know when just the pipes are empty.  The tank will gush out through the hose but the pipes will empty relatively slowly.  So empty the whole tank.  There are other ways but they are more work.
Recap: Turn the main off, turn the heater off, empty the tank, then cut the pipes.
Your question about using a mixer valve as a shut-off seems irrelevant to me, and I think the points in this answer hopefully show you it's not a good idea even if it works.
When your work is done, turn the water back on, and run hot and cold faucets on each floor until water and no air comes out everywhere. Then restart or relight the heater.
